# saving an immutable variable in a mapping in solidity?

Tags: mapping, solidity, immutability

I am trying to do something like this code below
any thought's ??

```
    mapping (uint256 => string immutable) public IdToAddress ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A map is a hash table. You cannot, therefore, set the value type to be immutable. Think of a map as a "key: value" pair where `idToAddress[uint256]` will return a string from the hash table in your example. It is not an array of data where you can return data by index. Not to mention that your syntax is wrong if this were to be introduced to solidity. Please note that you cannot set the data type after it is named.

**Therefore, you cannot accomplish this with mapping.**

You can read more in the solidity to find a use case that can suit your need:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html?highlight=mapping#mapping-types